# Laravel custom query for answer and question database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have three table called exams, questions and answers. They are connected via foreign id. I have function which i join questions and answers table. I have 1 question and multiple answers. When i join i see many same questions with 1 answer (which is normal). Is there any way to make join 1 question and multiple answers in one query(array) via query builder

Exams table

```
        $table->id();

        $table->string('language_code');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('subcategory_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('section');
        $table->string('class');
        $table->string('subject')->nullable();
        $table->string('time')->default('60');

        $table->timestamps();
```

Questions table

```
        $table->id();

        $table->integer('exam_id');
        $table->string('q_pic')->nullable();
        $table->string('q_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('q_text');

        $table->timestamps();
```

Answers table

```
        $table->id();

        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('question_id');
        $table->text('user_answer')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_answer_id');
        $table->integer('c_answer_id'); 

        $table->timestamps();
```

And here is my view function

```
public function view($id)
{
    $questions = DB::table('questions')
        ->leftJoin('answers','answers.question_id','=','questions.id')
        ->where('questions.exam_id','=',$id)
        ->get();

    return view('main/view',compact('questions'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the relationships right, you would not need a join to achieve this.

Your relationships should look like this:

**Exam model:**

```
public function questions()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

**Question model:**

```
public function exam()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
}

public function answers()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
```

**Answer model:**

```
public function question()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
}
```

Now you can query like this:

```
//use App\Question;
$questionsWithAnswers = Question::where('id', $id)->with('answers')->get();
```

This should give you a collection of questions with related answers.